# Tcp with javaFX cause error

Tags: tcp, javafx

I am trying to understand TCP for my Project. I have to make a game with Network in which client can watch the main player. For that I send the state data over tcp .
But after I initialze one `ChatClient` and call the method `set()` in `ChatClient` I got error.

I cant figure  out how to solve it.

```
package control;

import javafx.application.Platform;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ChatClient extends Thread {

    // TextField nachricht;
    ObjectInputStream ii;
    ChatScreen chat;
    GameScreen gamescreen;
    Socket socket;
    String name;
    ObjectOutputStream i;

    public ChatClient (String name, ChatScreen chat, GameScreen gamescreen) {
        this.chat = chat;
        this.gamescreen = gamescreen;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Diese Methode wird ausgeführt, wenn ein Client-Thread startet

        // Baue eine Verbindung zum entfernten Rechner auf
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9004)) {
            System.out.println(name);
            // this.chat.getButton().setText("w");
            // Öffne einen InputStream
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            i = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            ii = new ObjectInputStream(in);

            String line;

            try {
                line = (String) ii.readObject();
                System.out.print("text");
                if (line != null) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        gamescreen.getText().appendText(line + "\n");
                    });
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public GameScreen getGameScreen() {
        return gamescreen;
    }

    public void set() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            try {
                i.writeObject(name + ":" + chat.nachricht.getText() + "\n");
                i.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.print("ws");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Server:

```
package control;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Server for class {@link de.kaiguenster.javaintro.client.Client}, that handles all connections in their own Threads
 * 
 * @author Kai Günster
 */
public class MultithreadedServer {
    static ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> client = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int port = 9004;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        // this loop runs until the program is shut down (e.g. using `CTRL+C`)
        while (true) {
            // wait for connection
            Socket sock = server.accept();
            // When a connection is accepted, handle it in a new Thread
            new Thread(new AntwortProzess(sock)).start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a server Server
     * 
     * @param port
     *          Listen-Port
     */
    private MultithreadedServer (int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    private static void sendMessage(String nachricht) {

    }

    /**
     * Wait for connection and process it.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    /**
     * Runnable, to process incomming connections
     */
    private static class AntwortProzess extends Thread {

        private final Socket socket;

        public AntwortProzess (Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Diese Methode wird vom Thread gerufen, wenn er startet.
            try (Socket socket = this.socket) {
                System.out.print("true");

                /*
                  Wait 2 seconds first. This waiting priod happend in it's own 
                  Thread and doesn't prevent other connections to be accepted.
                  */
                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream i = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                ObjectInputStream ii = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                client.add(i);

                while (true) {
                    String line = (String) ii.readObject();

                    if (line != null) {

                        for (int b = 0; b < client.size(); b++) {

                            try {
                                client.get(b).writeObject(line + "\n");
                                // System.out.print(line);
                                client.get(b).flush();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
                // Write one line of text back to the client.
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Error:

> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
>           at control.ChatClient.run(ChatClient.java: 59)

Comment: Please format your Code the next Time. It makes it easier to read.

Comment: Delete the i.close() in your set() method.